# JQuery Mobile mobile.changePage instead of normal link

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I use JQuery Mobile 1.4.3 and JQuery 2.1.1 .And I use a normal link for transition buttons.But now all transitions are very slow.Skip to other pages takes 2-2.5 seconds.I've read few articles.And they say should use mobile.changePage() instead of normal links(such as:li>a href="page"..)* and should use "energize.js". İ found "energize.js" but I do not fully understand how to use.
These are my normal links.Links from the outside is changing according to the value so i dont understand how to use mobile.changePage() function.

```
 $.each(olayList, function(index, olay) {
                    if(olay.confirm==0){
                    $('#olayList').append('<li><a href="eventDetails.html?id=' + olay.id + '">' +
                            '<img src="pics/accept.png"/>' +
                            '<h4>' + olay.title + '</h4>' +
                            '<p> Accept </p>' +
                            '</a></li>');
                    }else if(olay.confirm==1){
                        $('#olayList').append('<li><a href="eventDetails.html?id=' + olay.id + '">' +
                                '<img src="pics/wait.png"/>' +
                                '<h4>' + olay.title + '</h4>' +
                                '<p> Wait </p>' +
                                '</a></li>');
                    }else if(olay.confirm==2){
                        $('#olayList').append('<li><a href="eventDetails.html?id=' + olay.id + '">' +
                                '<img src="pics/reject.png"/>' +
                                '<h4>' + olay.title + '</h4>' +
                                '<p> Reject </p>' +
                                '</a></li>');
                    }
                });
```

How can I use mobile.changePage() here based on the values?And can you tell me exactly how to use "energize.js" ??